# Passing vector by reference

Tags: c++

Using normal C arrays I'd do something like that:

```
void do_something(int el, int **arr)
{
   *arr[0] = el;
   // do something else
}
```

Now, I want to replace standard array with vector, and achieve the same results here:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> **arr)
{
   *arr.push_front(el); // this is what the function above does
}
```

But it displays "expression must have class type". How to do this properly?

Comment: ``int **arr``?? how to assign a 2d array directly? If you need 2d array, ``foo(vector<vector<int> > &arr)``.

Comment: I suppose he was probably trying to pass a pointer to an array not a two dimensional array..correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Lots of answers but nobody has noticed that it's an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. They want a `std::vector<int*>`.

Answer (score 38):

You can pass the container by reference in order to modify it in the function. What other answers haven’t addressed is that `std::vector` does not have a `push_front` member function. You can use the `insert()` member function on `vector` for O(n) insertion:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> &arr){
    arr.insert(arr.begin(), el);
}
```

Or use `std::deque` instead for amortised O(1) insertion:

```
void do_something(int el, std::deque<int> &arr){
    arr.push_front(el);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you define your function to take argument of  `std::vector<int>& arr` and integer value, then you can use  `push_back` inside that function:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    arr.push_back(el);
    //....
}
```

usage:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
do_something(1, arr);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> **arr)
```

should be

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    arr.push_back(el);
}
```

Pass by reference has been simplified to use the `&` in C++.

Comment: @taocp, what do you mean by 'Pass by reference has been simplified to use the & in C++.'?

Comment: @gen It's poor phrasing imho. What really changed in C++ was that it actually has pass-by-reference _at all_. C doesn't. It achieves the same results by passing pointers, and ruling that altering the result of a pointer dereference modifies the pointed value in its original place (not a temp copy). But that's not pass-by-reference. The pointer is passed by value.

Comment: @taocp Any idea, why accepting array of vectors as an argument gave an error: `vector <int> &v[100]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can **pass vector by reference** just like this:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> &arr){
    arr.push_back(el);
}
```

However, note that this function would always **add a new element at the back** of the vector, whereas your *array function* actually **modifies the first element (or initializes it value)**.

In order to achieve exactly the same result you should write:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> &arr){
    if (arr.size() == 0) { // can't modify value of non-existent element
        arr.push_back(el);
    } else {
        arr[0] = el;
    }
}
```

In this way you either add the first element (if the vector is empty) or modify its value (if there first element already exists).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use **arr, you can either use:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> *arr){
    arr->push_back(el);
}
```

or:

```
 void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> &arr){
    arr.push_back(el);
}
```

**arr makes no sense but if you insist using it, do it this way:

```
void do_something(int el, std::vector<int> **arr){
    (*arr)->push_back(el);
}
```

but again there is no reason to do so...